# Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I have a custom directive like this :

```
myApp.directive('input', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        link: function (scope, elem) {
            if (scope.lang && elem.attr('type') === 'text') {
                elem.attr('lang', 'fa');
                console.log(scope.lang);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

that add `lang='fa'` attribute to all input:text and also i'm using [DatePicker angular Ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) but i get an error :

```
    Error:   
    [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [datepickerPopupPersian, input] asking for  
      
     new/isolated scope on:  
     <input type="date" name="birth" class="form-control ng-pristine   
    ng-untouched ng-valid"  
     datepicker-popup-persian="{{formats.ShowDate}}" tabindex="7"   
    ng-model="requesterViewModel.BirthDate"   
    is-open="datePicker.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"  
 close-text="بسته"  
     max-date="dt">
```

when i comment datePicker in my form everything work well .
Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Your directive does not really need the scope; try using `scope:false`.

Comment: Hi my teacher :) , you saved my day yesterday ,  when i remove it , custom directive doesn't work because in my controller i've added this :     $scope.lang = 'faLang';

Comment: :) If you disable your `input` directive (totally comment out the code), does the problem persist?

Comment: no everything is okay , when i set scope to false one of my input get lang='fa'

Comment: hey buddy , please put your comment in answer section, that was my mistake and scope=false did the trick , thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This directive does not really need a new child scope (neither an isolated). It is much better to configure it with `scope: false`. It will not only correct this problem, but also save several (depending on the design of the views of course) unnecessary scope object creations.

Comment: i m getting the same error and my scope is set like this    
    
          scope: {
            onselectclient: '&',
            clientEntityType: '=',
            excludedClientIds: '=',
        },
what should i do here?